# Dealing with numbers that are too large for int in Java

Tags: java, parsing

So I am trying to parse a string containing a number too large for Int storage. But I need the value of the string because I am dividing it. Can I parse the string into a Long?

```
n = Long.parseLong(string);
```

like that? Or is there a way I can divid the string by a number without having to turn the string into a number? The code I am using is like this:

```
private static String getFinished(String x, int y){
    int word = Integer.parseInt(x);
    word = word/y;
```

And the number I am using is: 1980715126555015951540148577071512651650
But I could potentially be using numbers even longer.

Comment: If the number is less than or equal to 2^63 - 1 then you can use a `long`. If it's larger than that, use a `BigInteger`. More importantly, try it yourself and let us know if you get stuck with a real example.

Comment: Upvoting...  because it took me long enough to find the solution (already knowing it even) that I can see why you needed to post the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I parse the string into a Long?

Yes.  Provided that the number isn't too big.  The range for a long / Long is -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to +9,223,372,036,854,775,807.

Another alternative is to use `BigInteger` ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)).  It can cope with numbers that are even larger.  (The upper bound for `BigInteger` is most likely determined by the amount of memory you have available.)

> The number I am using is: 1980715126555015951540148577071512651650

That requires a BigInteger.  Example:

```
BigInteger small = new BigInteger("1980715126555015951540148577071512651650");
BigInteger notQuiteSoSmall = small.add(BigInteger.ONE);
```

Notes:

1. There is no operator overloading for `BigInteger`.  You have to use explicit method calls.
2. `BigInteger` objects are like `String` objects; i.e. they are immutable.  Arithmetic methods produce a new `BigInteger` object.

Comment: Can I use BigInteger the same way I would use the Int data type?

Comment: @TheTwistyTie No. `int` and `long` are primitives and can be used directly. `BigInteger` is an *immutable* object, so you must call methods to perform calculations. E.g. for an `int` you can say `i = i + 5`, but for a `BigInteger` you have to say `bi = bi.add(BigInteger.valueOf(5))`

Comment: No.  You have to use method calls to do arithmetic.  There are no overloads for the arithmetic operators.

Comment: So how would that look interms of parsing a string into a BigInteger?

Comment: @TheTwistyTie Look at the javadoc. StephenC has provided the link for you in the answer. There is a constructor you can use.

Answer (score 1):

The class you are looking for is `BigInteger`. Or `BigDecimal` for floats.

Answer (score 0):

No you can not divide a string without parsing it into a number.

And `long num = Long.parseLong(str);` is 100% legal, provided you wrapping it with a try/catch block or throwing exception from method.

Edit:
Based upon example string you added, `long` might not help you anymore. Check `BigInteger`.

Comment: Sure you can divide a string without parsing it into a number. It cumbersome, but you can do it exactly like you do it on paper.

Comment: Oh yea. but bigdecimal would all that for you internally. why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I agree, the right choice here is to use `BigInteger`, but I was simply contracting the statement you made in the first paragraph. It's wrong.

Comment: You are right. I did write BigInteger type implementation during my `c` days. :)